# Linking errors on VS2012 for CImageList and CBitmap apis

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am using mfc class CImageList in my project and using its APIs like Add(), Create() etc. It works fine with vs2010.
Now, I am upgrading the project to vs2012. It compiles and links fine for 32 bit platform, however throws below linking errors for 64 bit.

File1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol **imp_ImageList_ReplaceIcon referenced in function "public: int __cdecl CImageList::Add(struct HICON** *)"

File2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ImageList_AddMasked referenced in function "public: int __cdecl CImageList::Add(class CBitmap *,unsigned long)"

Similarly, below error is thrown for calling CBitmap api.

File2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CreateMappedBitmap referenced in function "public: int __cdecl CBitmap::LoadMappedBitmap(unsigned int,unsigned int,struct _COLORMAP *,int)"

It seems that the libraries having these implementations might have been changed. However, I could not find any clue on how to resolve them.

Comment: Are you trying to compile MFC?  The linker error appears to be on an MFC method, not your code.  Or does File1.cpp contain a copy of the MFC source for CImageList?

Comment: File1.cpp contains calls to MFC APIs. Below is the snippet of my code.  
  

  CImageList m_imgList;  
  
  m_imgList.Create(16, 16, ILC_MASK, 4,4);  
  m_imgList.Add(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(ID_ICON_UNCHECKED));  
  m_imgList.Add(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(ID_ICON_CHECKED));  
  m_ListCtrl.SetImageList(&m_imgList, LVSIL_STATE | LVSIL_NORMAL);

Comment: The linking error occurs for statement:    "m_imgList.Add(AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(ID_ICON_UNCHECKED)); ".  
It links properly for 32 bit platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the reason for this error.

ImageList_ReplaceIcon & CreateMappedBitmap symbols are present in comctl32.lib.
There was an older version comctl32.lib present in a path which was included in Additional Include Directories of my project settings.

So, instead of picking this lib from Microsoft SDK folder, the linker was picking from this directory and hence causing problems.